# prove $A \times B = B \times A \iff (A=B)\lor(A=\emptyset)\lor(B=\emptyset)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

had to prove the above mentioned iff, but I think I have something missing. would appreciate your advice.

[image]

Comment: This looks fine to me, but I would personally take the opposite approach. I would approach it as: "If $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$, then it is trivially true. Assume then that neither are empty, etc."

Comment: Your part (i)b doesn’t quite make sense to me. Your assumptions at that point are that $A\times B=B\times A$ and $A\neq B$. You then say “Let there be $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b)\in A\times B\to(b,a)\in B\times A$.” This fact alone about a pair $(a,b)$ is not very useful. Choose any $a$ and $b$ in neither of your sets, and it is true. You can’t conclude from this implication what you say after the word “thus.” For that to be true, you have to know that $(a,b)$ is in $A\times B$, but do you? You are close, but you need to improve this section.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice there was an answer. Will delete comment.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is okay. The first part is trivial and the second part is correct, but I would prefer:

Assume NOT the right side. That is $A\neq B$ and neither $A$ nor $B$ are empty. Then without loss of generality, there is $a\in A$ such that $a\not\in B$ and there is some $b\in B$.

Then the element $(a,b) \in A\times B$ but $(a,b)\not\in B\times A$.

Comment: You need to say “without loss of generality” to assert that there is $a\in A$ such that $a\notin B$, because it’s possible that $\emptyset \neq A\subsetneq B$, in which case what you say there is, there is not.

Comment: @SteveKass You are correct I meant to include that. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveKass You say that because the roles of $A$ and $B$ are entirely symmetric. So if this does not hold, it does hold if we interchange $A$ and $B$ in the rest of the argument.